# nonpersistant location permission in facebook webview android

Tags: android, facebook, webview, permissions, location

I developed an application that uses the geolocation of the user.

Everything works well everywhere, the permission request is well requested from users and remains persistent in browsers or android webviews.

On the other hand, in the webview of the facebook application on android, (but I think on iOs too) the page constantly asks for permission.
Whether when changing pages or when loading ajax gmaps. Do you have an idea of the reasons for the problem and especially the solution?

You can take the test by sharing the url https://www.street-art-safari.com/Feed (in private) on your profile and by accessing the site via the webview of the android/Ios application.

You will see that each time the webview asks again for permission all the time without saving it.